# Use property variables for the next action which is call by form

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, web-applications, struts2, action

I have one jsp web page which is the result of an iterator struts. In other words I have a list which is the result of an easy hibernate query `select from TABLE`.
Iterator struts2:

```
<s:iterator value="usersList">
   <s:property value="userName"/>
</s:iterator>
```

At the same time my jsp page has one form that has to call an other action. I'll call that

> classAction.java

classAction has to use the variable (**userName**) that I'll choose into the list.
Maybe I have to use `param`struts tag and something like a `select` struts tag (to tick the **userName** that I gonna use). Honestly I'm a bit confuse and I don't know exactly how to do what I want. 
usersList is a list of **User** object.

```
List<User> usersList
```

Any ideas it will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are having a `usersList` object and need to display it in a `selectbox` and get the selected value of the selectbox using a form.

Use struts `select` tag to display the `usersList` in a combo box.

```xml
<s:form action="useraction">
  // Assuming usersList is an object and that has a property username
  <s:select list="usersList" listKey="userName" listValue="userName" name="user" />
</s:form>
```

I am naming the action class as UserAction

```
public class UserAction{
  String user;
  // Getter and Setter methods
  ......

  public String execute(){
    // You know what to do with that userName
  }
}
```

Comment: Just splitting hairs, but what you are talking about here is a selectbox; a combobox is a combo between a textfield and a selectbox.